# django tastypie - how to diplay a link to the child objects

Tags: django, django-models, tastypie

I have two model classes: Blueprint and Workload.

A single Blueprint is, typically, a parent of multiple Workloads.

I have them defined in my models.py as follows:

```
class Blueprint(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=120)
    description = models.TextField()

    class Meta:
        ordering = ["name", ]


class Workload(models.Model):
    blueprint = models.ForeignKey(Blueprint)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=120)
    description = models.TextField()
    image = models.CharField(max_length=120)
    flavor = models.CharField(max_length=120)

    class Meta:
        ordering = ["name", ]
```

My api.py currently looks like this:

```
class WorkloadResource(ModelResource):
    def obj_create(self, bundle, request=None, **kwargs):
        return super(WorkloadResource, self).obj_create(bundle, request)

    def obj_update(self, bundle, request=None, **kwargs):

        workload = Workload.objects.get(id=kwargs.get("pk"))
        workload.description = bundle.data.get("description")
        workload.name = bundle.data.get("name")
        workload.image = bundle.data.get("image")
        workload.flavor = bundle.data.get("flavor")
        workload.save()

        def obj_delete(self, bundle, **kwargs):

            return super(WorkloadResource, self).obj_delete(bundle)

        def determine_format(self, request):
            return 'application/json'

    class Meta:
        queryset = Workload.objects.all()
        resource_name = 'workload'
        authorization=Authorization()


class BlueprintResource(ModelResource):
    def obj_create(self, bundle, request=None, **kwargs):
        return super(BlueprintResource, self).obj_create(bundle, request)

    def obj_update(self, bundle, request=None, **kwargs):

        blueprint = Blueprint.objects.get(id=kwargs.get("pk"))
        blueprint.description = bundle.data.get("description")
        blueprint.name = bundle.data.get("name")
        blueprint.workloads = bundle.data.get("workloads")
        blueprint.save()

    def obj_delete(self, bundle, **kwargs):

        return super(BlueprintResource, self).obj_delete(bundle)

    class Meta:
        queryset = Blueprint.objects.all()
        resource_name = 'blueprint'
        authorization = Authorization()
```

When I run a GET method against /api/blueprint/ , I expect to get the Workload link URL from the api, but, when I run:

```
curl -i -H "Accept: application/json" -H "Content-Type: application/json" -X GET http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/blueprint/1/
```

all I get is:

```
{"description": "First Blueprint", "id": 1, "name": "Blueprint 1", "resource_uri": "/api/blueprint/1/"}
```

and no mention of the child Workload url.

What changes do I need to make in order to get this additional link, pointing to the location of the Workload children?

Comment: Update:  I'm now able to get the Blueprint link, by including the following line into my WorkloadResource:        blueprint = fields.ForeignKey(BlueprintResource, 'blueprint', full=True).  But would still need help with figuring out how to get the link, which point to the Blueprint's Workload children when calling GET on /api/blueprint/1

Comment: What if you do `full=False`. Does that give you the link instead of the data? Or do you want both?

Comment: I realized, I could do this "the other way around" :  GET /api/workload/?blueprint=1     While it is a separate call, it does give me just the workloads, which are children of blueprint 1